# How to rename last part of file name

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, rename, batch-rename

I have a number of files to rename, I want to remove _thumb in existing name.

```
Eg: 00700008_thumb.jpg
    00800104_thumb.jpg
    01200004_thumb.jpg
```

I want to rename the above files as:

```
Eg: 00700008.jpg
    00800104.jpg
    01200004.jpg
```

Using below code how to separate the part.

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SourceDir=F:\Square.....

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=. " %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%\*.jpg"') DO (
  SET "part1=%%~F" 
  SET "part2=%%~G" 
  SET "part3=%%~H"
  REN "%SourceDir%\!part1! !part2!.!part3!" "00!part2!.!part3!"
)
GOTO EOF
```

How can I rename the files?

Comment: What's the result of the code you provided? Looks like you're already renaming the files?

Comment: This is the 6th time you have asked a very similar question. Please take some time to learn how the answers that you have been provided with solve the problems. You will then be able to make the required changes yourself in future.

Comment: @Seth He's just pasting similar code from his other 5 questions and expecting us to tweak it every time. See my other comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your issue is to rename those files, according to your examples, you could just `cd` to the folder you want and issue the following command:

```
for /F "useback tokens=1 delims=_" %I IN (`dir /B /A-D *.jpg`) DO (ren %~I_thumb.jpg %~I.jpg)
```

Comment: This sounds good @m4573r

Comment: @dbenham no it doesn't; see the `delims=_`? `%I` contains only `00700008`. But I would consider making the dir `*_thumb.jpg` in case there are any other files around.

Comment: Oops, that was embarrassing. @dave_thompson_085 - Thanks for pointing out the DELIMS that I had missed.